# Redux form и проблемный инпут

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

Есть две формы,регисnрация и авторизация.С регистрацией все норм.
Проблема в том что если я сначала вписываю почту первым то вылетает ошибка в консоль,а если начинаю вписывать сначала пароль,а потом почту то все ок.

Дело в том что инпут регистрации идентичет авторизации и я не пойму в чем проблема.

```js
import React from "react";
import classes from "./auth.module.scss";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { required, PasswordCheck } from "../../untils/validators/validators";
import { authInput } from "../commons/formsControls/formsControls";
import { UserisAuth } from "../../redux/authReducer";

const FormBox = props => {

  const MinValue=PasswordCheck(5)
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Емейл</label>
        <Field component={authInput} type="email" name="email" validate={[required,]}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">Пароль</label>
        <Field component={authInput} type="password" name="password" validate={[required,MinValue]}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button className={classes.submited}>Войти</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const LoginForm = reduxForm({
  form: "login"
})(FormBox);

const Login = (formData) => {
  let onSubmit=(formData)=>{
 //UserisAuth(formData)
console.log(formData)
}
  return (
    <div className={classes.formbox}>
      <div className={classes.form}>
        <h5 className={classes.formtitle}>Вход</h5>
        <LoginForm onSubmit={onSubmit}></LoginForm>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Validator

```js
export const required = value => {
  if (value) return undefined;
  return "Это обязательное поле";
};

export const PasswordCheck = MinValue => value => {
  
  if (value.length < MinValue) return `Пароль не может быть меньше ${MinValue} символов`;
  return undefined;
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в штуке MinValue но чему это значение затрагивает другое поле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем надо const MinValue=PasswordCheck(5) вынести за процедуру и все работает.

Сам спросил,сам ответил

```js
import React from "react";
import classes from "./auth.module.scss";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { authInput } from "../commons/formsControls/formsControls";
import { required, PasswordCheck } from "../../untils/validators/validators";
  const MinValue=PasswordCheck(5)
const SignUpBox = props => {

  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="FIO">ФИО</label>
        <Field component={authInput} type="text" name="FIO" validate={[required,]}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="username">Никнейм</label>
        <Field component={authInput} type="text" name="username" validate={[required,]}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Емейл</label>
        <Field component={authInput} type="email" name="email" validate={[required,]}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">Пароль</label>
        <Field component={authInput} type="password" name="password" validate={[required,MinValue]}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button className={classes.submited}>Завершить</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const SignUpForm = reduxForm({
  form: "signUp"
})(SignUpBox);

const SignUp = () => {
  let onSubmit=(formData)=>{
    console.log(formData)
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.formbox}>
      <div className={classes.form}>
        <h5 className={classes.formtitle}>Регистрация</h5>
        <SignUpForm onSubmit={onSubmit}></SignUpForm>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```